# git: ERROR: Permission denied to deploy key

Tags: git, github, ssh

Recently I've set `gpg` keys to make signed commits and push to GitHub.

- At GitHub, I've configured deploy user `NecktwiMech` to push with ssh authentication.
- I have configured in `~/.ssh/config` to use `id_rsa.NecktwiMech` while ssh to github.com.
- I've also added `GPG` auth key obtained from `ssh-add -L` to GitHub `Necktwi` account.
- For forked project named `bcmrpi3-kernel-bis`, I've added `NecktwiMech` as a collaborator with push access.

but when I push, I get the following output:

```
btrfs_root:bcmrpi3-kernel-bis Necktwi$ git push --set-upstream origin btrfs_root
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
ERROR: Permission to Necktwi/bcmrpi3-kernel-bis.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

btrfs_root:bcmrpi3-kernel-bis Necktwi$ git remote get-url origin
git@github.com:Necktwi/bcmrpi3-kernel-bis.git
```

but `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com` says authentication succeeds:

```
btrfs_root:bcmrpi3-kernel-bis Necktwi$ ssh -vvvT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/Necktwi/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/config line 13: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-80573d3e
debug1: no match: babeld-80573d3e
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/Necktwi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/known_hosts:61
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/Necktwi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/known_hosts:61
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/Necktwi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/Necktwi/.ssh/known_hosts:67
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.30.253.112
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Necktwi/.ssh/known_hosts:61
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: (none) RSA SHA256:QZB+ZPD3ltV1QVQsd4eLnNY2myF4yGK3cwMSl/abPo8 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: (none) RSA SHA256:QZB+ZPD3ltV1QVQsd4eLnNY2myF4yGK3cwMSl/abPo8 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: (none) RSA SHA256:QZB+ZPD3ltV1QVQsd4eLnNY2myF4yGK3cwMSl/abPo8 agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:QZB+ZPD3ltV1QVQsd4eLnNY2myF4yGK3cwMSl/abPo8
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
debug1: Offering public key: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug1: could not add identity to agent: /home/Necktwi/.ssh/id_rsa (-27)
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.112]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug3: Ignored env CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK
debug3: Ignored env DISTCC_VERBOSE
debug3: Ignored env TMUX
debug1: Sending env LANGUAGE = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env CCH_DCC_PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PREV_PS1
debug3: Ignored env GPG_TTY
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_ORIG_PS1
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env CONFIG_PROTECT
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DISTCC_TCP_CORK
debug3: Ignored env CCACHE_DIR
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env UNCACHED_ERR_FD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env DISTCC_FALLBACK
debug3: Ignored env DCC_EMAILLOG_WHOM_TO_BLAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env INFOPATH
debug3: Ignored env DCC_PATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env TMUX_PANE
debug3: Ignored env MANPAGER
debug3: Ignored env VISUAL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env DISTCC_SAVE_TEMPS
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env DISTCC_SSH
debug1: Sending env LC_MESSAGES = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env GCC_SPECS
debug3: Ignored env PS1
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env DISTCC_ENABLE_DISCREPANCY_EMAIL
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LC_COLLATE = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env CCH_PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 94
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 7 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 7/(94)
Hi Necktwi/musl! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 94 to efd 7
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 7 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/7 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3820, received 2536 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7662.5, received 5086.9
debug1: Exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a deploy key on GitHub, it can either be read-only or read-write. If you want to push data, the key has to support write operations, but it looks like currently your key is set as read-only.

You can remove the key and re-add it, checking the “Allow write access” box, which will let it push to the repository.